# How do you embed a youtube video on an html page on top of an image in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, dreamweaver

The webpage is all html. No css. I don't know css. I used this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7XpOzJHRU4&list=FLSvViAYel69qti8gklYJJnw&index=1&feature=plpp_video) to take my site designed in photoshop and make it with Dreamweaver.

I just want to simply embed a Youtube video in a specific position on the page. But the only to embed the video is to push down one of the images and put the video beside it. I want the video to be embedded on top of the page layout as if it floats there in front of the image behind it.

As you can tell, I have no idea what I'm doing.

I want the video to be on the page like this [site](http://www.dollarshaveclub.com/).

Comment: Can you post some html and css

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code of the provided site, the video itself is running inside a div. If you don't wish to use css just define the properties directly on the style for the div which will be the container for the video as follows:

```
<div style="background: url(http://www.dollarshaveclub.com/skin/frontend/dsc-test/dsc-theme/images/video_placeholder.png) no-repeat; padding: 18px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <iframe width="537" height="301" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZUG9qYTJMsI?rel=0&autohide=1&autoplay=0"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Test it on jsfiddle: [Clic here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgqyf/)

*BTW: Change the background url for your background image file's location, the code for the video (gather it from youtube) and the width and height of the div accordingly to the dimensions of the video in order to customize.*

Good luck!